# Xampp on windows 8 : Error Attemting to start tomcat service

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, xampp

```
                    Tomcat Service detected with wrong path
```

```
2:11:08 PM  [Tomcat]   Change XAMPP Tomcat and Control Panel settings or
```

```
2:11:08 PM  [Tomcat]   Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
```

```
2:11:08 PM  [Tomcat]   Found Path: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\Tomcat7.exe" //RS//Tomcat7
```

```
2:11:08 PM  [Tomcat]    Expected Path: c:\xampp\tomcat\bin\tomcat7.exe //RS//Tomcat7
```

i have already installed tomcat appache 7 in my computer. and now i want to run my jsp project on xampp control panel's tomcat. so i change port 8080 to 8090. but still tomcat is not running and display only Attempting to start tomcat service.
please help me.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you have installed tomcat windows service installation package.

This error does not affect anything, even though if you want to remove the error. Just run xampp controller with administrator access and uninstall tomcat service.

If you want to run tomcat service, you can install it again so that it will take tomcat location from your xampp directory.

Step 1:
[Open XAMPP - Run as administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9fZu.png)

Step 2:
 [Tomcat service must be install with different location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFWXF.jpg)

Step 3:  [Click on green arrow in beside tomcat to uninstall current service.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASYQ7.jpg)

Repeat these steps if you want to install tomcat service again or just install it by clicking on red cross next to tomcat.